# Amazon Braket Token Exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, quantum-computing

I am attempting to run a job on Amazon Braket via the integrated Jupyter Notebooks, but I'm receiving an "ExpiredTokenException when calling GetQuantumTask operation" upon attempts to submit the job. Would anyone have any guidance on how to fix this?

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Please add Exception log along with your GetQuantumTask call

Comment: see also same post on qc: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16583/55